# Using command line, how do I get m out n possible results of each type?

Tags: regex, linux, unix, awk, sed

Lets say I have shelves in a store and each shelf has 0-9 boxes of specific kind. I want to select no more than 4 boxes from each shelf and only till I have 15 in total. How do I write a command line code where the input file is something like

```
AA123 small
AA124 small
AA122 small
BB345 medium
..
..
100s of such
```

Where first 2 letters define the shelf and number tell the box number on that shelf.

For finding unique shelves, I could use

```
cat filename | awk '{print $1}' | cut -c 1-2 | sort | uniq | xargs
```

Then I was trying to use this as input in for/while loop but got stuck.

Comment: May I ask why you want to solve this with a shell script?

Comment: where is the filename given in your command?

Comment: I think your command should be `awk '{print $1}' file | cut -c 1-2 | sort | uniq | xargs`

Comment: I am not particular about solving it only by shell script. Any other suggestion is welcome. I edited the Q to add the filename input that was not obvious earlier.

Answer (score 2):

I think `awk` is the right tool for this.

The following one liner prints the first four occurrences of shelves, and only up to 15 in total:

```
awk 'a[substr($1,1,2)]++ < 4 {if (t++>14) exit; print}' file
```

Comment: Nice, although I think you can remove the `{ }` from around the whole thing and use the first part as the condition: `a[substr($1,1,2)]++ < 4 {if (t++>14) exit; print}`